# Find the highest concentration areas

Tags: r

I have a large data set (2 million rows) where each rows represents a point with its spatial coordinates in meter (x and y) and its score. It looks like this:

```
my_points <- data.frame(ID = 1:2e6, 
    x = sample(x = 1:1e6, size = 2e6, replace = TRUE), 
    y = sample(x = 1:1e6, size = 2e6, replace = TRUE), 
    Score = sample(x = 1:1e3, size = 2e6, replace = TRUE))

head(my_points)
# ID      x      y Score
#  1  21984 628151    54
#  2 675714  27715   431
#  3 273248 127287    47
#  4 659750 795394   921
#  5 478142 417083   416
#  6 783249 440782   253
```

All the points are located in a large area (1000 x 1000 kilometers).

I'm trying to find the groups of points within a radius of 100 meters that gather the highest score.

I have tried two solutions so far, but none of them were able to handle so much data (even with parallel computing or `data.table` package):

**1st solution:**

I have built a spatial grid that covers all the space. I chose a small step for the grid (10 meters) to be sure I gather all the possible solutions. For each point of the grid, I sum the score of the points that are less than 100 meters away.
This solution takes way too much time (maybe weeks or months on my computer)...

**2nd solution**

I have build a function that, for a couple (x, y), returns the score contained within the circle of center (x, y) and of radius 100 meters.
I have tried to find the maximas of this function but I was not able to find an appropriate methodology for this kind of non-continuous function...

Any ideas for a faster solution (less than a day) ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok - I think my solution works, but it's much to slow.

```
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp(code = '
  #include <Rcpp.h>

  using namespace Rcpp;

  // determine, if a point is in a polygon
  bool pnp(NumericVector vertx, NumericVector verty, float testx, float testy) {

    int nvert = vertx.size();
    bool c = FALSE;
    int i, j = 0;

    for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
      if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) &&
           (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
        c = !c;
    }

    return c;
  }

  // create a circle polygon (36 corners) around a point with a certain radius
  NumericMatrix circle(float centerx, float centery, float radius){

    int pnum = 36;
    double rotation = 2 * 3.14159 / pnum;
    NumericMatrix res(36, 2);

    for (int p1 = 0; p1 < pnum; ++p1) {
        double rot = p1 * rotation;
        res(p1, 0) = centerx + cos(rot) * radius;
        res(p1, 1) = centery + sin(rot) * radius;
    }

    return res;
  }

  // create a vector with the circle score sum of each point 
  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  NumericVector searchmaxclust(DataFrame points) {

    Function asMatrix("as.matrix");

    SEXP points2m = points;
    NumericMatrix pm = asMatrix(points2m);

    NumericVector co(pm.nrow());

    for (int p1 = 0; p1 < pm.nrow(); p1++) {
      NumericVector curp = pm(p1,_);
      NumericMatrix circ = circle(curp(1), curp(2), 100.0);

      for (int p2 = 0; p2 < pm.nrow(); p2++) {
        NumericVector curp2 = pm(p2,_);
        bool isin = pnp(circ(_,0), circ(_,1), curp2(1), curp2(2));

        if (isin) {
          co(p1) = co(p1) + curp2(3);
        }

      }

    }

    return co;
  }
')
```

I use Rcpp to speed things up - the algorithm is quite simple.

1. Create a circle polygon around each point
2. Check for all the other points if they are within the circle polygon and add up all the scores of the correct ones

It takes about 0.6s for 1000 points. I guess that means, that it will take about a month for your 2000000 points. Hm. I decided to post this anyway. Maybe it helps somebody else.

Comment: Thank you @nevrome ! However in your solution you are only testing the initial points as circle centers. But the center of the area that gather the highest score has no reason to be a point of my initial data...

Comment: Oh - ok. An other idea: Maybe image analysis with the raster package is the way to go. They've implemented very fast algorithms for raster data.